# Account creation across trusted OAuth2 client and server

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have two *trusted* web properties `Product A` and `Product B` where I want to find or create a corresponding account on `Product B` using email whenever I create an account on `Product A`. What's the proper way to accomplish that in the realm of OAuth2?

To put it another way, from my understanding, regular Oauth2 flow will require the user to manually authorize `Product A` to access `Product B` by redirecting user to `Product B` to login or create a user before continue on `Product A`. I'd like to skip this step and allow account on `Product B` to be automatically created without user interaction. I can think of some custom ways to accomplish it, but how do I achieve that following OAuth2 best practices?

Comment: You need to be more specific in what are the roles of *Product A*  and * Product B*. (Client application, Web API, mix of both, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Why create the account?

OAuth has no abilities to create or to modify an account.

OAuth only provides DELEGATION of permissions by the end-user to an application.

Often sites will create a unique Identity Information Entry on their site to store site specific preferences or "tracking" information in that entry. Hoe this is performed varies widely but SCIM is fast becoming the "Standard" method to use.

-jim

Comment: I want an account to be created on Product B when an account is created on Product A. One way I can think could accomplish this is posting an Authorization Code to Product B right after account creation on A. Although OAuth itself didn't say anything about account creation, but in practice when you login through Facebook to some third party service for the first time, an account will be created on that service. I'm wondering if there are some best practices etc.